# How to get all members from GAL "ExchangeUser.Department" using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm looking for a way of geting all members of a specified department like the advanced search function on the Outlook address list using VBA.
[The function I would like to replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svn72.png)

The code below ([for reference](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/solved-global-address-list-gal-search-without-for-loop-addressentry-getexchangeuser.681132/)) gives me the opposite function. I can input a userID/alias and it will give me "any other" info about that user.

```
Public Function GetDepartment(var1)

 Dim outApp As Object 'Application
   Dim outTI As Object 'TaskItem
   Dim outRec As Object 'Recipient
   Dim outAL As Object 'AddressList


    Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    Set outAL = outApp.Session.addressLists.Item("Global Address List")
    Set outTI = outApp.CreateItem(3)
    
    outTI.Assign
    
    Set outRec = outTI.Recipients.Add(var1)
    outRec.Resolve
    If outRec.Resolved Then
        'MsgBox outRec.addressEntry.Name
        Department = outRec.addressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Department
        'MsgBox outRec.addressEntry.GetExchangeUser.JobTitle
        'MsgBox outRec.addressEntry.GetExchangeUser.
        'MsgBox outAL.addressEntries(outRec.addressEntry.manager.Name).GetExchangeUser.Alias
    Else
        Department = "Couldn't find Employee Department"
    End If
  
GetDepartment = Department  
    
End Function
```

Due to the amount of entries in GAL using a iterative approach is not feasible.

not sure but maybe the "List members" from [here](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/use-vba-to-create-a-list-of-exchange-gal-members/) can be modified to work but I'm code savvy enough to do it.

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box functionality for that, Department is a free text fields in Exchange, and it does not keep a list of entries that share the same value of the Department attribute.

You *can* loop through all entries in GAL (especially in the cached mode when the whole GAL is downloaded locally), it is just not advisable to do that in VBA - Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) is the right tool for this.